# how to compare file txt input by percentage

Tags: python, compare

need for little assitance, how can i make python to compare input to an existing file by %?

for example:

file 1:
this is a butifull day

user input:
what a butifull day right?

the unput has 3/5 word from the file 1 so its around 60%.

how can i do it in my code?

the spicific area is
" elif user in client:"

```
def cindex(msg):
#add client input to "client" file
with open("client_index.txt", "a") as client:
    client.write(msg)
    client.write("\n")
    client.close()
#open and compare the files
with open("user_index.txt", "r") as user:
    with open("client_index.txt", "r") as client:
        same = set(user).intersection(client)
        for line in same:
            print(line, end='')
        if msg == "[Please reactivate the user!]":
            driver.find_element("xpath", "//textarea[@id='chat-windows-message-textarea']").send_keys('same')
        elif user in client:
            driver.find_element("xpath", "//textarea[@id='chat-windows-message-textarea']").send_keys('yap')
        else:
            driver.find_element("xpath", "//textarea[@id='chat-windows-message-textarea']").send_keys('nope')
```

Comment: Convert the user input and the file contents into sets of words. Then get the length of the intersection of the two sets. Calculate the percentage of this to the length of the file.

Comment: can you example of what you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Class FileComp:
  
  def __init__(self, existing, newinput):
    
    self.existing_file = existing
    self.input_file = newinput
    self.matches = 0
    self.percentage = 0
  
  def read_existing(self):
    
    with open(self.existing_file, 'r') as f:
      check_against = [a for a in f]
      f.close()
      return check_against
  
  def read_input(self):
    
    with open(self.input_file, 'r') as e:
      words = [c for c in e]
      e.close()
      return words
  
  def compare(self, ca, ui):
    
    for i in range(0, len(ui)):
      if ui[i] in ca:
        self.matches = self.matches + 1
        
    self.percentage = (self.matches*100) / len(ca)
    return self.percentage

def main():
    newcompare = FileComp("client_index.txt", "user_index.txt")
    check_against = newcompare.read_existing()
    user_input = newcompare.read_input()
    result = newcompare.compare(check_against, user_input)
    print(result+" %")
    
main()
```

Comment: `[a for a in f]` can be simplified to just `list(f)` or `f.readlines()`. But you need to split it into words, not lines.

Comment: So use `words = e.read().split()`